# Android Studio(0.2.0) Unit test No output on logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, android-testing

When I write a unit test on Android Studio(0.2.0) with some log output, but alfter I ran it , there are no logs except

```
09-13 11:16:39.747  20963-20978/com.wanshangle I/TestRunner: started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.wanshangle.api.test.AsyncHttpRequestTest)
09-13 11:16:39.747  20963-20978/com.wanshangle I/TestRunner: finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.wanshangle.api.test.AsyncHttpRequestTest)
09-13 11:16:39.747  20963-20978/com.wanshangle I/TestRunner: passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.wanshangle.api.test.AsyncHttpRequestTest)
```

Comment: can you share the code as well, so we can look at it?

Answer (score 4):

By default when running unit tests in android studio it shows you a runner log window, this only relates to the actual running though. If you wan't to see the log you get from Log.x you have to open the LogCat window. You'll find this under "View->Tool Windows->Android":

[image: Android Studio LogCat view]

Comment: The issue for me was this filter being active: `app:com.my.package.name`. There's a dropdown box to the right of the Log Level one that let's you change the filter. I could see the LogCat output after I did that.

Comment: Now I know how to do with it, Thanks @Almund

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Almund's answer:

If you want that the Android-Monitor stays visible and (and not switching back to the Run-Window) you'll *uncheck* "activate Tool-Window" in your tests "Run configuration..."

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed in Android Studio since the last answer, but this is still a problem.  I haven't figured out how to see regular Log statements, but I have found that System.println() commands can be viewed.

This trick works as of *Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1*.

Select Run -> Edit Configurations

[image]

Click on **Modify Options**.

[image]

Make sure that there is a check mark next to **Specify logs to be shown in console**.

[image]

click **OK** and you should be good.

NOTE:  System.println() messages will now display in the **test results** log (not the logcat).

Wish I had a better solution.